# Completely overwriting collection in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an endpoint that will take a list of objects that correspond to one of my Models. I want to treat this collection as the entirety of a Model's table and atomically drop-and-then-repopulate it on each call to Post. Is there a way to do this other than doing `Model.delete_all` and then `Model.create` for each element in the list? If it matters, we're using MySQL and the attendant adapter in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Repopulate the same data that was deleted in the same table?

Comment: New dataset, overwriting old dataset.

Comment: Simply update the collection records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what would be the use-case for such a behaviour, so I won't try to offer a suggestion on your algorithm decision (although at a first glance, it sounds like an odd decision to drop-and-repopulate). Anyway, assuming that you have planned, and decided that you really want to drop and repopulate, then `delete_all` and then `create` should do the trick.

You can `create` more than one object at the same time (or you can look at a gem for bulk import to make the process a bit faster. [1]

One thing you should keep in mind is to keep the whole code within a transaction, so in case the repopulation fails, you do not lose all of your data:

```
ModelName.transaction do
  ModelName.delete_all
  ModelName.import [:col1, :col2], new_records
end
```

[1] https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import